# Clone and rename id and name

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone and rename id and names but the following code doesn't seem to be working. Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions?

It looks like the following line has problem.

cloned.id = what.attr('id') + "_" + cur_num;

Here is my function.

```
       var cur_num = 1;    // Counter
    $("#btnClone").click(function(){

          var what = $("#MainConfig"); 
          var where = $("#smallConfig");

          var cloned = what.clone(true, true).get(0);
          ++cur_num;
          cloned.id = what.attr('id') + "_" + cur_num;                  // Change the div itself.

        $(cloned).find("*").each(function(index, element) {   // And all inner elements.
          if(element.id)
          {
              var matches = element.id.match(/(.+)_\d+/);
              if(matches && matches.length >= 2)            
                  element.id = matches[1] + "_" + cur_num;
          }
          if(element.name)
          {
              var matches = element.name.match(/(.+)_\d+/);
              if(matches && matches.length >= 2)            
                  element.name = matches[1] + "_" + cur_num;
          }

         });

       $(cloned).appendTo(where);

    });
});
```

Comment: you seem to be somewhat confused between jQuery collection object and actual DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

To use the features of jQuery, you need to reference the "what" variable with the proper syntax. You should use "$(what)" instead of "what".

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the ID in a different variable. You are trying to save the ID into a jQuery object.